# Scala Type Mismatch Mapping

Tags: scala, mismatch

I am trying to create a search function, so the user can search through a list using the key value, however the method Im trying to use returns a type mismatch, Have taken out needless code and shown what is required. How do I set points to take an Int and not "Any"?

"type Any does not conform to type Int"

```
  val mapdata = readFile("data.txt")


  def handleTwo(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowPointsForTeam(currentPointsForTeam)
    true
  }




def mnuShowPointsForTeam(f: (String) => (String, Int)) = {
    print("Team>")
    val data = f(readLine)
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2}")
  }



  def currentPointsForTeam(team: String): (String, Int) = {
    val points = mapdata.get(team) match{
      case Some(p) => p
      case None => 0
    }
    (team, points)
  }
```

The data.txt

```
SK1, 9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1
SK2, 0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1
SK4, 2, 9, 5, 7, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5, 4, 0, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8
SK5, 2, 6, 8, 0, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3
SK6, 2, 7, 5, 9, 1, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 7, 0, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 4, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 9
SK7, 6, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 3, 8, 7, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 1, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0
SK8, 2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 0, 8, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 7, 0, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 8, 6
SK9, 7, 1, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 9, 7, 2, 6, 6
```

Comment: What is the type of `mapData`? What is the return value for `mnuShowPointsForTeam` (now it just printlns)?

Comment: updated the question, mapdata is an external txt file, yes it just printlns the team thats key value is entered @Thilo

Comment: But what is the type of `mapData`? Is it `Map[String, Any]`? If you cannot make that `Map[String, Int]` then you have to convert/cast to Int inside of that `case Some(p)` part.

Comment: The map data is Map(String, List[Int]), how would I do that @Thilo?

Comment: Then `p` will be `List[Int]`.  How do you want to get an `Int` from that? Or should your return type be `(String, List[Int])` instead? Your function `currentPointsForTeam` wants to return a `(String, Int)` now, not a `(String, List[Int])`.

Comment: Return type I think should be a string list int

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127850/discussion-between-andre-queen-and-thilo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to return a tuple with a `List[Int]`, not just a single `Int`.

If so

```
def currentPointsForTeam(team: String): (String, List[Int]) = 
  (team, mapdata.get(team).getOrElse(List.empty))
    // Or maybe List(0) instead of List.empty
```

If you do want to return a single `Int`, you have to say how to go from the `List[Int]` in the map to a single value.  Maybe a sum?

```
def currentPointsForTeam(team: String): (String, Int) = 
  (team, mapdata.get(team).map(_.sum).getOrElse(0))
```

Comment: Head of the nail, that is exactly what I was trying to achieve! thanks

Comment: First example worked great however the second takes in a String Int and not a String List int, how would that work? Just tested it and I get a type mismatch @Thilo

Comment: Ignore that last comment, typed before I thought! Thats it working now, thanks again